# Modifying colors of geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having problems to group colors and present them in legend. The function takes in one level that is not within the data (3rd), and shows it in the legend, but does not do the same with 4th.

```
x <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1498521600, 1498525200, 1498528800, 
1498532400, 1498536000, 1498539600, 1498543200, 1498546800, 1498550400, 
1498554000, 1498557600, 1498561200, 1498564800, 1498568400, 1498572000, 
1498575600, 1498579200, 1498582800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), irish_rules_sensitive = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("date", "irish_rules_sensitive"
), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
color_var_sens <- vector(mode = "double",length = length(x$irish_rules_sensitive))
color_var_sens[color_var_sens== '0']<- NA
color_var_sens[x$irish_rules_sensitive>=1 & x$irish_rules_sensitive<=3] <- "#FFFF00" 
color_var_sens[x$irish_rules_sensitive>=3 & x$irish_rules_sensitive<6] <- "#FFAA00" 
color_var_sens[x$irish_rules_sensitive>=6 & x$irish_rules_sensitive<9] <- "#FF5500"
color_var_sens[x$irish_rules_sensitive>=12] <- "#FF0000" 


p5 <- ggplot(x)+ 
  geom_col(aes(x = date, y = irish_rules_sensitive, color = color_var_sens, group = 1), size= 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 40) )+
  labs(x="", y="Accum. EBHours")+
  scale_color_identity("Modified Irish Rules", breaks= rev(levels(as.factor(color_var_sens)))[c(1,2,3,4)], 
                       labels = c("Low ","Medium", "High", "Very High"),
                       guide = "legend",drop = FALSE)
p5 + guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=c("#FFFF00","#FFAA00","#FF5500", "#FF0000" ))), size = "none")
```

The weird thing is that this sometimes works and result should be something like this: [image]

Error code:

```
    Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, v, value = c("#FFFF00", "#FFAA00",  : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because `color_var_sens` is not a factor and the `guide_legend` tries do replace values that do not exist in `color_car_sens`. You should make it a factor. In that way you do not need the`guide_legend`:

```
color_var_sens <- factor(level=rev(c("#FFFF00","#FFAA00","#FF5500", "#FF0000" )), ordered=T)
color_var_sens[color_var_sens== '0']<- NA
color_var_sens[x$irish_rules_sensitive>=1 & x$irish_rules_sensitive<=3] <- "#FFFF00" 
color_var_sens[x$irish_rules_sensitive>=3 & x$irish_rules_sensitive<6] <- "#FFAA00" 
color_var_sens[x$irish_rules_sensitive>=6 & x$irish_rules_sensitive<9] <- "#FF5500"
color_var_sens[x$irish_rules_sensitive>=12] <- "#FF0000" 


ggplot(x,aes(x = date, y = irish_rules_sensitive, fill = color_var_sens))+ 
  geom_col( size= 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 40) ) +
  labs(x="", y="Accum. EBHours") +
  scale_fill_identity("Modified Irish Rules", breaks= rev(levels(as.factor(color_var_sens))), 
                       labels = c("Low ","Medium", "High", "Very High"),
                       guide = "legend",drop = FALSE)
```